# how can i test conditionals of a regex

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to a figure out a way to find out if a condition statement in a regex evaluated to true or false. i'm very new to regular expression so sorry if this is an obvious question.

side note: there are multiple regexs and they are constantly changing.I am also using java to make this app.

any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest you check out RegExr http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. It's really nice tool to build and test regex. There's also a desktop version http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/

Comment: Do you mean regex conditionals like explained in the [regular-expressions.info site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write unit tests, asserting the common cases you are trying to match.

The canonical testing library for java is [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)

Comment: the job of the program is to make test statement but there are too many regexs to create them manually.

Comment: There's no information on your question to infer that you wanted to auto-generate regexes. Please provide more context and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: sorry i know my previous comment was not clear,what I meant was that there are too many regexs and they don't have enough in common for me to create tests manually.